# Backup repository size is much bigger than indices size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch backup per hour, after about 370 times of backup (about 15 days) , my backup repository is more than 15G !!! But the total indices size is just about 500M !! Elasticsearch is incremental backup, but 15G VS 500M , the difference is so huge ! I wonder whether it is normal with so big different size between indices and backup repository ?

Is it caused by my frequent backup (hourly) ? I use the hourly backup in cluster 1 and hourly restore in cluster 2 to keep two ES clusters data same real time .

I am using Elasticsearch backup API to backup

1. setting repo: 
   curl -XPUT "http://IP:9200/_snapshot/backup" -d "{\"type\": \"fs\",\"settings\": {\"compress\" : true,\"location\": \"backup\"}}"
2. backup : 
   CURTIME=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
   BKTIME=${CURTIME//[- :]/}
   curl -XPUT "[http://IP:9200/*snapshot/backup/snapshot*](http://IP:9200/_snapshot/backup/snapshot_)$BKTIME?wait_for_completion=true"

My Elasticsearch settings : 2 nodes , 12 shard/node , 2 indices , fs type of backup to store snapshots to NAS

in Elasticsearch data directory , the indices size :

node1 indices size : 
[root@esnode1 indices]$ du -sh

307M .

node2 indices size
[root@esnode2 indices]$ du -sh

238M .

[root@esnode1 indices]$ du -lh

8.0K    ./index1/10/translog
8.0K    ./index1/10/_state
2.9M    ./index1/10/index
2.9M    ./index1/10
12K     ./index1/5/translog
8.0K    ./index1/5/_state
1.5M    ./index1/5/index
1.5M    ./index1/5
8.0K    ./index1/4/translog
8.0K    ./index1/4/_state
2.9M    ./index1/4/index
2.9M    ./index1/4
8.0K    ./index1/_state
8.0K    ./index1/7/translog
8.0K    ./index1/7/_state
2.9M    ./index1/7/index
2.9M    ./index1/7
8.0K    ./index1/1/translog
8.0K    ./index1/1/_state
2.9M    ./index1/1/index
2.9M    ./index1/1
8.0K    ./index1/2/translog
8.0K    ./index1/2/_state
2.9M    ./index1/2/index
2.9M    ./index1/2
8.0K    ./index1/6/translog
8.0K    ./index1/6/_state
3.0M    ./index1/6/index
3.0M    ./index1/6
8.0K    ./index1/0/translog
8.0K    ./index1/0/_state
1.5M    ./index1/0/index
1.5M    ./index1/0
8.0K    ./index1/8/translog
8.0K    ./index1/8/_state
1.5M    ./index1/8/index
1.5M    ./index1/8
8.0K    ./index1/11/translog
8.0K    ./index1/11/_state
2.9M    ./index1/11/index
2.9M    ./index1/11
12K     ./index1/9/translog
8.0K    ./index1/9/_state
3.0M    ./index1/9/index
3.0M    ./index1/9
8.0K    ./index1/3/translog
8.0K    ./index1/3/_state
3.0M    ./index1/3/index
3.0M    ./index1/3
31M     ./index1
16K     ./index2/10/translog
8.0K    ./index2/10/_state
16M     ./index2/10/index
16M     ./index2/10
36K     ./index2/5/translog
8.0K    ./index2/5/_state
43M     ./index2/5/index
43M     ./index2/5
20K     ./index2/4/translog
8.0K    ./index2/4/_state
17M     ./index2/4/index
18M     ./index2/4
8.0K    ./index2/_state
40K     ./index2/7/translog
8.0K    ./index2/7/_state
32M     ./index2/7/index
32M     ./index2/7
68K     ./index2/1/translog
8.0K    ./index2/1/_state
21M     ./index2/1/index
21M     ./index2/1
64K     ./index2/2/translog
8.0K    ./index2/2/_state
19M     ./index2/2/index
19M     ./index2/2
116K    ./index2/6/translog
8.0K    ./index2/6/_state
22M     ./index2/6/index
22M     ./index2/6
24K     ./index2/0/translog
8.0K    ./index2/0/_state
17M     ./index2/0/index
17M     ./index2/0
128K    ./index2/8/translog
8.0K    ./index2/8/_state
34M     ./index2/8/index
34M     ./index2/8
72K     ./index2/11/translog
8.0K    ./index2/11/_state
20M     ./index2/11/index
20M     ./index2/11
88K     ./index2/9/translog
8.0K    ./index2/9/_state
22M     ./index2/9/index
22M     ./index2/9
76K     ./index2/3/translog
8.0K    ./index2/3/_state
16M     ./index2/3/index
16M     ./index2/3
277M    ./index2
307M    .

in backup repository , the size :
[root@esnode1 backup]$ du -lh

114M ./backup/indices/index1/0

112M ./backup/indices/index1/5

114M ./backup/indices/index1/11

114M ./backup/indices/index1/10

111M ./backup/indices/index1/8

116M ./backup/indices/index1/4

120M ./backup/indices/index1/9

118M ./backup/indices/index1/3

114M ./backup/indices/index1/2

115M ./backup/indices/index1/7

115M ./backup/indices/index1/1

112M ./backup/indices/index1/6

1.4G ./backup/indices/index1

747M ./backup/indices/index2/0

1.6G ./backup/indices/index2/5

887M ./backup/indices/index2/11

743M ./backup/indices/index2/10

2.1G ./backup/indices/index2/8

801M ./backup/indices/index2/4

1.3G ./backup/indices/index2/9

878M ./backup/indices/index2/3

951M ./backup/indices/index2/2

1.2G ./backup/indices/index2/7

953M ./backup/indices/index2/1

943M ./backup/indices/index2/6

13G ./backup/indices/index2

15G ./backup/indices

15G ./backup

1.1M ./backuplogs

15G .

======
https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-snapshot-restore
Both backup and restore operations are incremental, which means that only files that changed since the last snapshot will be copied into the repository or restored into an index. **Incremental snapshots allow performing the snapshot operation as frequently as needed without too much disk space overhead.** Users can now easily create a snapshot before upgrade or a risky change in the cluster and quickly rollback to the previous index state if things go wrong. The snapshot/restore mechanism can be also used to synchronize data between a “hot” cluster and a remote, “cold” backup cluster in a different geographic region for fast disaster recovery.

From the above , my case is really an issue , Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: How do you trigger your hourly backup?

Comment: add a linux cron job in  /var/spool/cron/root
0 1 * * * /opt/es/ESBackup.sh >> /backup/log/backup_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).log

Comment: Is your shell script using snapshot/restore or are you just copying the data folders? In the latter case, know that you should not copy data folders without closing your indices first, otherwise you run the risk of copying inconsistent data.

Comment: I am using Elasticsearch backup/restore API

    setting repo: curl -XPUT "http://IP:9200/_snapshot/backup" -d "{\"type\": \"fs\",\"settings\": {\"compress\" : true,\"location\": \"backup\"}}"
    backup :

CURTIME=date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

BKTIME=${CURTIME//[- :]/}

curl -XPUT "http://IP:9200/snapshot/backup/snapshot$BKTIME?wait_for_completion=true"

Comment: Can you edit/update your question with `du -lh` of your data folder ?

Comment: updated , Thanks , this is my 1st time to post question here , Thanks for your quick response :-)

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed in Elasticsearch official forum

1) It is a normal result that the indexes and backup repository have a big different size (500G VS 15G) in my case

2) Some of redundant data in backup snapshots are caused by segment merge of Lucene

From Elasticsearch expert : If you are constantly indexing into the cluster, merging of segments will continously happen in the background and the same record will end up in multiple segments over time, resulting in a repository that is considerably larger than the index size.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/backup-repository-size-is-much-bigger-than-indices-size/47469/7

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot and restore works at the segment level it is very important information that isn't mentioned in Elastic "Snapshot And Restore" documentation.
I reported this to Elastic and asked if they can update the documentation.